# Stream of Firebase documents on add documents event?

Tags: firebase, stream, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Stream that gets the latest snapshot of a firebase collection, I need to attach an event to scroll down the List view that displays this collection of docs

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: model.getConversation(widget.channelId),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapShot) {
                    if (snapShot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child:
                            Text('Please check your Internet Connection'),
                      );
                    } else if (snapShot.data.documents.length == 0) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('no Messages yet'),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                        controller: _scrollCont,
                        children: snapShot.data.documents
                            .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                          return Msg(
                            text: document.data['message'].toString(),
                            msgTime: document.data['creation_time'],
                            isMe: document.data['sender_id'] ==
                                model.user.userProfile.id,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      );
                    }
                  })
```

what I need to do is scrolling the view to the last element whenever any new message arrives in the messages collection,

Comment: Can you clarify the question ?

Comment: @aziza I have a collection of chat messages I'm using a stream to get the latest snapshots of those document so I want to fire a function whenever a new document gets added to this collection, I'm thinking of storing a variable holding the last index of those documents then if any change happens to that index I will fire the function, Is there's a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: `getConversation(widget.channelId)` how are you managing your stream here ?

Comment: this the function it takes a document id and return the snapshot of this document 


getConversation(String channelId) {
    Stream streamReceiver = Firestore.instance
        .collection('chat_rooms')
        .document(channelId)
        .collection('messages')
        .snapshots();

    return streamReceiver;
  }

Comment: you need to listen on the `messages` collection directly, maybe use a nested stream builder, the first one will get one chat room document, the inner one will listen on the messages, this way the inner one will update itself whenever a new message is added, and the outer one will update itself whenever a new chat room is created

Comment: Already doing this but on separate screens, what I need to do is scrolling the view to the last element whenever any new message arrives in the messages collection,

Comment: call `_scrollCont.animateTo(_scrollCont.position.maxScrollExtent...)` inside stream builder, each time an update will happen stream builder will trigger a rebuild, calling the `animateTo` method again to jump to the end.